# How to use Axios in main.js

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I am learning Vue.js.

I have this code which runs fine :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

const app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

Now I would like to add some import, for example 'axios'. This code does not run :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import axios from 'axios'

const app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router).use(axios)

app.mount('#app')
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

    at merge (utils.js?c532:276)
    at assignValue (utils.js?c532:282)
    at forEach (utils.js?c532:253)
    at merge (utils.js?c532:291)
    at assignValue (utils.js?c532:282)
    at forEach (utils.js?c532:253)
    at merge (utils.js?c532:291)
    at assignValue (utils.js?c532:282)
    at forEach (utils.js?c532:253)
    at merge (utils.js?c532:291)
```

So how to add some other "use" in the main.js file ? It is certainly very basic but I am a beginner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using vue 3 and axios is not a plugin (we cannot register it like `app.use()`) it's a javascript module that could be add to the app instance like :

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import axios from 'axios'

const app = createApp(App).use(store).use(router)

app.config.globalProperties.axios=axios

app.mount('#app')
```

and in child component reference it like :

```
this.axios
```

Answer (score 4):

**Note: the code below is valid for Vue 2.x. Since version 3, some stuff has changed regarding initialization (`createApp` function is now required).**

What I usually do in my code is the following:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

// Add it to Vue prototype (use any variable you like, preferrably prefixed with a $).
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;

// Instantiate the main vue app.
let app = new Vue({
  //
});
```

This means that the `$http` object is now available in all your components using `this.$http`. Since it is assigned as a prototype variable, it is considered a singleton (it is re-used everywhere), so you can add any options you need to the `axios` variable before assigning it to `Vue.prototype.$http`.

Additionally:
`Vue.use()` is made specifically for enabling Vue plugins. That means the given parameter must use the exact syntax as described here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html . Since axios is not a Vue plugin but just a regular JavaScript library, you cannot use it with this function.

If you want to make it especially nice (or convoluted), you can use the following syntax:

```js
Vue.use({
    install(v) {
        v.prototype.$http = axios;

        // Do other stuff like adding mixins etc.
    }
})
```

This may clear up your code if you move this code to another file, so it could end up like this:

```
import myCustomAxiosLoader from './bootstrap/axios';
Vue.use(myCustomAxiosLoader);
```

Comment: Your syntax is valid for vue version 2, please mention that in your answer

Comment: thanks I've added it for clarity. Didn't know they changed some of this syntax in 3.x. Apparently if you want to migrate to v3 and change this initializiation in your app, it should mostly work as-is.

Comment: you're welcome, there's some breaking changes like the global api